# What does "Awaiting Assignment to Batch" mean?

Tags: publications, peer-review, journals, journal-workflow

My paper was accepted a week ago, at that time the status in the ScholarOne manuscript center changed from "accept" to "awaiting production checklist". They also said I would receive an email regarding the proof check. However, till today I haven't received any email. Today the status again changed to "Awaiting Assignment to Batch". I am curious what is this mean? According to the journal, it takes 2 weeks(on average) to get published "online pre-print" from the acceptance date. I am just worried if I am missing something.

Answer (score 5):

First, congratulations!!

"Awaiting Assignment to Batch" is part of the accepted workflow. Once accepted, some journals have a set of tasks that a manuscript goes through. One of the steps available (and being used here) is batching and sending of the manuscript to the journals production service. It will wait until a predetermined condition (so many ready to go, or a regular timed interval), then be added to a large zip file (along with others in the "batch"), and sent to the production server.

Hope this helps!

NOTE: I am am employee of ScholarOne, but my opinions and answers are only my own.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is my first time submitting in a journal so I am just anxious.